# How to avoid pan map at initial zoom view

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I would like to avoid to pan map at initial zoom, when application is loadded and starts user's interaction. The normal behavior of Openlayers 3 is allow user to make pan (if he wants) just to the middle of the map, but I need to restrict this at initial zoom to prevent to show cartography out of the bbox.

Is possible to do it?

Changing extent of map I didn't get expected result.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting only relevant portion of the code

```
  var panInteraction = new ol.interaction.DragPan();

  var map = new ol.Map({
      layers: [raster, vector],
      interactions : [panInteraction],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [-11000000, 4600000],
          zoom: 4
        })
  });

  var zoomLevel = map.getView().getZoom();

  if (zoomLevel == 4) {
      panInteraction.setActive(false);
      //alert("deactivating");
  }
```

Comment: Great answer. Testing it, I've noticed that mobile devices users wants to pan map always. Restriction should works only in case of desktop device.

Is possible to limit the pan control to a bbox and don't have the option to move map if map view is the same or similar to the extent of the map? Something similar to a "MaxPanExtent" ? Thanks again

Comment: Although i don't know the exact answer to that question, I think it will be easier to use ol.View settings for that kind of behavior. Also methods like ol.extent.containsExtent may be handy after you get extent by map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());  . But before trying that, check this link if you can gather some useful info : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118383/openlayers-3-max-extent